# Searching substring in string

Tags: c, for-loop, substring

So, i have been trying to create program that i failed to do in a test. It should be capable of 1) searching a word in substring. I got that part with some help down. Now comes the part where user inputs a number(here its a k), and the program prints out the words in front of/behind the word in string. I think it should be done by counting characters(here an s) until i encounter one more Space character than is the value of the input number(should be m). For some reason however, when this loop ends, the s is always equal to m.

```
for(int h = 0; h < 100; h++){
        if (*(found+h) = ' '){
            m++;
        }
        s++;
        if(m > k){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show some possible input outputs?

Comment: The whole text is loaded from a file. Up till i fixed it thanks to nicomp (oh the mistakes one makes). So basically, if you got input as 4, then despite the fact that there were 32 characters (and so the loop should have repeated 32 times), it only looped 5 times. I think i will post the whole code once i finish it. There might be fellow beginner students who might appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (*(found+h) = ' '){
```

should be

```
if (*(found+h) == ' '){
```

you need a test for equality.

Comment: Maybe to add a short explanation why this code still compiles: If you use an assignment (single `=` character) then this assignment is executed first and after that a boolean check is executed. In your case you check a `char` which equals to true as long as it does not equal to a character which integer representation is 0 (should be `'\0'`).

Comment: Some compilers might emit "*result of assignment used as truth value ... add parentheses ...*".

Comment: Some other compilers might emit the warning "Possibly incorrect use of assignment in line..."